# Windows Powershell: Error message when calling "help" or other unrecognized functions

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm receiving the following error in Powershell when trying to execute certain functions. For instance, typing "help dir" results in this:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin> help dir
The term "more.com" is not recognized as a cmdlet ...
At line: 14 char: 22
*    $input: | more.com <<<<
```

I was attempting to use " | more" earlier and can only assume it somehow appended this error message, but I have no idea how to get rid of it. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: what is you os / PS version ? try with get-help dir

Comment: windows 7 (86x) / PS version 1. get-help dir worked, so thanks! though i'm still unsure about getting rid of that error message when i run into other errors

Comment: More.com should be in your C:\Windows\System32 dir.  Can you check to see if it is there? If it is, perhaps your PATH env var has gotten messed up.  Look at it in PowerShell e.g. `$env:path`.

Comment: why dont you upgrade PS to V2 or V3 ??

Comment: Do you have a PowerShell_profile.ps1 script in your C:\Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowershell folder? You can set aliases and create functions in this file and maybe something is a bit dodgy in there.

Answer (score 1):

I added C:\Windows\System32 (back for some reason) to the PATH environment variable, rebooted, and BOOM, back in it to win it.

Not sure why it went missing, but it did.